# nginx1.8 Laravel 502 bad gateway error

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, homestead

SOLVED!

Using Virtualbox to setup Homestead vagrantbox
Here is the server configuration in the file dev.blog.com.conf

```
    server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   dev.blog.com;
    root          /vagrant/blog/public;
    index         index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
      index  index.php index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri @rewrite;
   }

   location @rewrite {
     rewrite ^ /index.php;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     include fastcgi.conf;
   }
   access_log /vagrant/logs/blog.access.log;
   error_log /vagrant/logs/blog.error.log;
   }
```

And in VagrantFile I've uncommented the line 'config.vm.network'

In My windows hosts file I've add this line

```
 192.168.33.10  dev.blog.com
```

I keep restarting Nginx or refreshing the page,but still got the 502 bad gatway.
It's there some permission problem about my folder or other problems?

Log

```
2017/02/17 02:16:54 [error] 1717#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: dev.blog.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.33.10" 
2017/02/17 02:17:02 [error] 1717#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: dev.blog.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.33.10"
```

Comment: "What does the _log_ say?" - Ylvis

Comment: 2017/02/17 02:16:54 [error] 1717#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: dev.blog.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.33.10"
2017/02/17 02:17:02 [error] 1717#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: dev.blog.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.33.10"

Comment: you are browsing to `http://dev.blog.com` right? please note the http

Comment: It still cannot work.I've tried add http:// to  dev.blog.com and 192.168.33.10

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the Problem,The new php configuration had been modified a little bit,so in the

```
vim /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

so the listen line should be `listen=9000` instead of `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`